# Difference between Iframe and position div

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am having an issue about the pop and `iframe`.

I want to show a window or `div` to pop in the center of the screen to show the contents.

My question is, should I use `iframe` or `position div` for this type of requirment.

What's the main different between these. I thought `position div` will basically replace the

`iframe`. Am I right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what may I ask is a `position div`?

Comment: div with absolute position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` and an `iframe` no matter what the position type of the `div` are not equivalent.

An `iframe` has a `src` attribute that lets it load external or other internal html pages within your current page. You cannot do this with a `div` by itself.

There are ways around this, however it sounds like your just showing a modal popup. In which case you should use a `div`. Unless you have a need to load external html an `iframe` is not the answer.